# Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver (development branch) is stable now?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

```
30th November: Feature Definition Freeze --
4th January: Alpha 1 release --
1st February: Alpha 2 release --
1st March: Feature Freeze -- 
8th March: First beta release --
5th April: Final beta release --
19th April: Final Freeze -- 
26th April: Stable Ubuntu 18.04 LTS release --
```

Comment: _26th April: Stable Ubuntu_ - in Germany, it's 5th April. Did you invent a time machine?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. 
I use that and now is stable and fast. Don't have so heavy startup memory using and have a great visual if you install a preferred theme. The only thing I think about the Develop Branch is for the automatic update for a stable branch after the official launch.

I suggest you download from this URL (official):
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Be happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Well as i know they say one should wait till the first patch (eg. 18.04.01) before updating. Often *sudo apt-get dist-upgrade* offers it after that is being released. But i believe 18.04. shouldn't be unsafe.